# html5/css3: Footer with "position:fixed" glitching

Tags: html, css

**The question was answered.**

At my website, I have a footer that should be fixed at the bottom of the page with a width of 100%. It was working before, but once of a sudden it didn't (?)

This is the HTML code for the footer:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/footer.css">

<div class="footerHolder">

</div>
```

This is the CSS code for the footer:

```
* {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}

div.footerHolder {
margin: 0;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 25px;
border: 1px solid black;
transition: height 1s;
-webkit-transition: height 1s;
}
```

Of course the CSS file is named "footer.css" and stored in the folder css. That's not the problem. The footer shows up somewhere lined up with another object. You can look at it here:
[My website](http://www.ysbakker.eu/beta/). If you look at it, you'll see the lower box, not lining up as I want it... It seems to be lining up with the main box and header box, but I'm not sure how to fix that. I've tried several things like floating it to the left but that wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source you posted on your question is incomplete, but looking at your site source's the problem comes from the fact that your `div#headerHolder` is not closed.

This is the CodePen equivalent to your site: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zEjfl. It renders well on CodePen site, even with the missing `</div>`.

---

***Note:** You don't have to repeat `* { ... }` in all your CSS files, they are "merged" from the browser's perspective*

Comment: Woops, you're right. That's why it didn't work. I removed a </div> too much. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `left` CSS attribute, which needs to be specified when using `fixed` positioning. Add

```
left: 0;
```

to your CSS for *div.footerHolder*.

Comment: It's weird though, it worked before without the left attribute. I removed a menu bar lined up with the header and it glitched... Weird. Well thanks again

Comment: You should not need `left: 0`, nor `right: 0`; and `width: 100%` should be enough. The real problem is the unclosed `div`, as pointed out in my answer!

Comment: @YSbakker accepting the answer would make me a happy fellow :)

Comment: @Dropout Yeah well I couldn't do that before, sorry. And I'm not sure what answer to accept, they both worked for me. I guess I'll accept snooze92's, indeed, as you said, the real issue was the unclosed div. Sorry Dropout, thanks for answering me though :)